# What is the best way to query information out of a collection from within a document in RavenDB

Tags: nosql, ravendb

For example say I have the following class

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the following document

```
var document = new Parent
{
    Id = "parent/1",
    Name = "1",
    Children = new List<Parent.Child>
    {
        new Parent.Child {Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 2)},
        new Parent.Child {Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 3)},
        new Parent.Child {Date = new DateTime(2013, 1, 4)},
    }
};
```

How do I:

1. Ask RavenDB to give me the instance of Child with date 2013/1/4 without sending the whole document over?
2. Profile my query to make sure I am doing the correct thing?

Comment: Please separate the profiling part to a new question and add more detail about what you want to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you don't want to do this.  The whole point of a document database is that a document represents an entire aggregate root entity (in Domain Driven Design terminology).  One would expect that in the document that you described that all "Children" would be relevant to the root "Parent".

For a real world example, consider a SalesOrder that has LineItems.  Would it makes sense to retrieve just a single line from the order?  Probably not.  You would retrieve the entire SalesOrder - including all LineItems.

This is an important concept to understand.  In an RDBMS (like SQL Server), you would need two separate tables to store an order and its line items.  To retrieve an order, you'd have to read 1 record from the SalesOrders table, and N records from the LineItems table.  This anti-pattern is commonly referred to as "Select N+1", and it causes major scalability problems when, for example, retrieving many orders in bulk.

So the best answer is, don't query at all.  Do a simple `session.Load<Parent>("parents/1")` and you will have all the children data as well, with a single call to the database.  Thus avoiding Select N+1 issues.

...

Now for the more complex answer - yes you *can* get just part of the document back. Typically you wouldn't do this for a single document though.  You might want to do it for querying against multiple documents that have specific criteria.

For example, say you want to answer the query, "Give me all Children that have a specific Date".  This would be a query with an index projection.

By default, Raven is geared towards returning entire documents, not partial documents.  In other words, we would normally answer the related query "Give me all Parents that have any Children that have a specific date".  That query looks like this:

```
var parents = session.Query<Parent>()
                     .Where(p=> p.Children.Any(c=> c.Date == theDate))
                     .ToList();
```

You could take the results of this query and filter out the children you wanted using linq-to-objects on the client side (after the above `ToList` call)

```
var children = parents.SelectMany(p=> p.Children.Where(c=> c.Date == theDate));
```

This would *work*, but it's not that efficient because you threw out a lot of the data you got back from the database.

The alternative would be to do this in one call using a static index with a projection.  First, the index definition:

```
public class ChildrenIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Parent>
{
    public ChildrenIndex()
    {
        Map = parents => from parent in parents
                         from child in parent.Children
                         select new
                         {
                             child.Date,
                             child.Name
                         };

        StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

Then the query:

```
session.Query<Parent.Child, ChildrenIndex>()
       .Where(x => x.Date == theDate)
       .AsProjection<Parent.Child>();
```

*Note that the `Parent.Child` syntax is just because you have `Child` as a nested class of `Parent`.*

In the index, we map the fields that we are going to want to project, and we *store* those fields so they can be retrieved.  I used the `StoreAllFields` shorthand syntax, but you could also just mark each field separately with `Store("FieldName", FieldStorage.Yes)`.

In the query, the first time I specify `Parent.Child` is so I can query by it in the `Where` predicate.  Left alone here, the result would still be the containing `Parent`.  So we use `AsProjection` to tell raven we really want to project the fields that we stored, rather than giving back the document that matched the index terms.

...

Now hopefully you can see that this is overkill for returning just one child out of one parent, and you should just load the whole parent for that.

If you find yourself loading specific children a lot, it could be that a child in your context really is its own aggregate and should be in its own document.  You could still relate the parent and child, either by storing a `ParentId` on the child document, or a `ChildrenIds` list on the parent, or both.

Comment: Thanks Matt, the reason why I don't want to store each child as Documents is because the child contains only two integers. The child collections are roughly 10k in length and RavenDB seems to be taking up spaces to append metadata to the child. I tired the Projection solution but couldn't figure out how to limit the query by parent's ID.

Comment: If you know the parent's id - just load the parent directly.  You can then pull out whatever data you want.  Just think of each child like it's any other property of the parent.  Say you wanted to get just the parent's name - you would load the parent and use the name property. it's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Would RavenDB be smart enough to load JUST the child with Date = DateTime.Now from a Parent with a given parentId? Wouldn't that give me the entire collection of children?

Comment: No, you can't project from a load - at least not in 2.0.  I believe that is coming in 2.5 with results transformers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the context here?  You say there are 10k children in a parent? Are they put in all at once? Or are you constantly reading/writing the parent doc to add new items - such as recording sensor data?

Comment: Your going to flood a single document very quickly.  Either store each child in its own document, or group them in buckets, such as by day.  Probably each "day" should be a market day - not a UTC datetime.  If you're only recording a couple per day, then make your buckets larger, like per week or per month.

Comment: This is for storing stock market data. If you imagine storing Exponential Moving Average (EMA), I can have a parentId of "IBM-EMA-9Days" and the child is just a pair of Date and values. So really, I just want the query to tell me what is the latest Ema value for IBM-EMA-9Days so I can do can add to the child collection.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27649/discussion-between-matt-johnson-and-chi-chan)

Comment: Thank you, I took the advice with inverting the relationship as in the discussion.